# How to resize a div in html/css

Tags: html, css

I have a nice looking card, I want to make it a little bit smaller.

```css
  :root {
  --links: yellow;
}

#header {
  text-align: center;
}

#links {
  text-align: center;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* 5px rounded corners */
}

img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.container {
  padding:
```

```html
<div class="card" button data-autobuy-product="62011137-f68d-4855-6346-08d8082eae6a">
  <img src="onetap_master.jpg" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>Onetap Master Config</b></h4>
    <p>Receive the config, lifetime updates & premium javascripts</p>
  </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/dark.min.css">
<script src="https://autobuy.io/js/embed.min.js"></script>
```

The card is width wise just a bit to long and I'm wondering if it's possible to make it either more narrow or just smaller in general

Comment: You can't achieve what you want with the `width` and `height` properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```html
<div class="card" button data-autobuy-product="62011137-f68d-4855-6346-08d8082eae6a">
    <img src="onetap_master.jpg"alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>Onetap Master Config</b></h4>
      <p>Receive the config, lifetime updates & premium javascripts</p>
    </div>
  </div> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/dark.min.css">
<script src="https://autobuy.io/js/embed.min.js"></script>
<style>    
:root {
    --links: yellow;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
}

#links {
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px; /* 5px rounded corners */
  width: 40%;
  height: 35%;
}

img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 

</style>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, this is perfect.edit: wil accept answer in 9 minutes

Answer (score 2):

Handle it with percentages?

```
.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px; /* 5px rounded corners */
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a Bootstrap card. You can resize it using these resize options from Bootstrap:
[Card Sizing](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#sizing)

Answer (score 1):

Give the `card` class a width what you want, it will resize the card. And give the image fixed `height`.

```css
:root {
    --links: yellow;
}

#header {
    text-align: center;
}

#links {
    text-align: center;
}

.card {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px; /* 5px rounded corners */
  width: 500px;
}

img {
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card" button data-autobuy-product="62011137-f68d-4855-6346-08d8082eae6a">
    <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%; height: 300px;">
    <div class="container">
      <h4><b>Onetap Master Config</b></h4>
      <p>Receive the config, lifetime updates & premium javascripts</p>
    </div>
  </div> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kognise/water.css@latest/dist/dark.min.css">
<script src="https://autobuy.io/js/embed.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Q is very "wrong" - This issue not related specifically to this card.
The card is a simple div. div is a block element:

> block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element
> (container)
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements

```
.card {
  width: 25%;
}
```

or

```
.card {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Now what? (How to add more cards one next to each other? How to make this responsive...)

My advice to you is to follow some `basic HTML-CSS` course and later learn about `CSS layout` (Flexbox & CSS grid).

#### Card Height & Overflow

Fixed `height` (300px, 30% or 20em) may cause overflow issues("content overflows an element's box") .
Some solutions: Use `min-height` instead of `height` -or- define [overflow property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

```html
<div style="background:red; height: 60px;">
    <p>text overflow issue</p>
    <p>text overflow issue</p>
    <p>I am out of the card</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `width` property in your CSS to resize the height of your `div`.

```
.card {
  width: [specify width here];
}
```

`width` can be specified using `px`,`cm`, `%`, etc, according to your needs. You can read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_width.asp).